# How to move objects with views to next activity in android?

Tags: android, class, serialization, android-activity

In my android app, I have an object `A` that has a global variable with value of another object `B` and `B` has a linearlayout global variable.

I want to transfer `A` to a new activity. The usual way is to put it in the intent as serialized string. But I don't think it can be done when `B` has a linearlayout since it can't be serialized. I don't need the object `B` anymore when moving it.

Does anyone know a way to transfer the object? Maybe some way to remove the `B` object before sending it?

Thanks

Comment: Some code will help, have you tried parcelable?

Comment: it seems to me that you're making a mess between `UI` classes and `data` classes. The biggest separation you get from them the better.

Comment: If I get you right, why you don't just use A.B = null; before you create the string?